# 正規分布のグラフに色を塗る

Tags: java, r

以下のようにJRIを使って正規分布のグラフを作り画像として保存しています。

```java
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
public class JriTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--no-save"}, false, null);
        engine.eval("png('curve.png', 640, 480)");
        engine.eval("curve(dnorm(x,0,1),-4,4)");
        engine.eval("dev.off()");
        engine.end();
    }
}
```

これで作ったグラフのある一定値より右側（もしくは左側）に色を塗りたいのですがやり方がわかりません。
教えてくださると幸いです。

Comment: [やり方教えていただいたので一応ここに回答として残しておきますね。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66059/%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E5%88%86%E5%B8%83%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%AB%E8%89%B2%E3%82%92%E5%A1%97%E3%82%8B)

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [正規分布の下に色を塗る。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66059/%e6%ad%a3%e8%a6%8f%e5%88%86%e5%b8%83%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%ab%e8%89%b2%e3%82%92%e5%a1%97%e3%82%8b)